# which tool to see the exported class and method from a dll

Tags: visual-c++

which tool to see the exported class and method from a dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see imported and exported symbols, I highly recommend the free Dependency Walker tool which can be found there: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It can show C as well as C++ symbols by correctly demangling Visual C++ exported function names.

Answer (score 2):

**Are you looking for the [DUMPBIN.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) that comes with Visual Studio?** You can use it it to display information about in COFF binary files, executable files, and DLL files.

Use it with the [`/exports` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30e78zd0.aspx) to display all definitions that are exported from an executable or DLL. Remember that you have to run it from a command prompt that has the `PATH` set up properly; look for the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" in your Start menu.

For more information, see the Knowledge Base article here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429

Comment: There is also a GUI version of the tool, available here: http://www.cheztabor.com/dumpbinGUI/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to disassemble it to see the methods, but the classes, you can't ever really recover, because most of the information has been compiled away and practically impossible to get back.

Take a look at [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) (trial) for a disassembler.