# Read linker information from a dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a C++ DLL built with Visual Studio 2012, but lack the source code.

I want to know what functions I can call from it and if possible, the namespaces and classes that are accessible. Is there a way to find everything that is usable in the dll?

Comment: The list of exported functions you can find with depends.exe (dependencywalker.com). Other than that, you can disassemble the DLL and try to figure what functions it contains and what parameters they take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dumpbin` will tell you all the dll exports when invoked with the `/EXPORTS` option.

> dumpbin /EXPORTS mydll.dll

Comment: And `dumpbin` is available in the developer command prompt in Visual Studio Tools. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [DUMPBIN.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) is what you are looking for. But please use the search function as this answer has already been provided several times e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644803/which-tool-to-see-the-exported-class-and-method-from-a-dll).